# Does this loop run in $\mathcal{O}(n^4)$ time?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computational-complexity

A double loop is given:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
    for (int j = i; j < N; j++)
        sum++;
```

My analysis: The inner loop runs $n$ times the first iteration, then $n-1$, $n-2$, $n-3$, $n-4$ until it gets to $n-n$ which is zero. This is a series summation which is expressed as: $$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2}(n(n+1))= \frac{1}{2}(n^2+n)= \frac{1}{2}n^2 + \frac{1}{2}n$$ Discarding lower terms and constants give $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{2}n^2\right) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

The outer loop is executed $n^2$ times. Multiplying by the inner loop gives $\mathcal{O}(n^4)$. Is this right?

Update: Now I think the actual answer is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ because the inner loop is only executed half the times of the outer loop.

Comment: You're factoring in the outer loop twice - you effectively factor it in once when you compute your (series) summation, but then multiply by it as well.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I just realized that. See my update at the bottom. Is this correct?

Comment: You're much more on the right track - though for a formal analysis I would split the outer loop into the two pieces $0\leq i\lt N$ and $N\leq i\lt N^2$.  (Note that you still _run_ the inner loop over the latter case, even though you don't execute any statements within it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By splitting the outer loop into $0\leq i\leq N-1$ and $N\leq i\leq N^2-1$ (because the code inside the inner loop isn't executed at all for $i\geq N$, but still costs $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time to do) we obtain:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i}^{N-1}1+\sum_{i=N}^{N^2-1}1&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(N-1-i+1)+N^2-1-N+1\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}N-\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}i+N^2-N\\
&=N^2-\frac{(N-1)N}{2}+N^2-N\\
&=\mathcal{O}(N^2).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Is this a quicker way to do what I did?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is quicker, but I find it easier to apply, since you can just interpret every loop as a sum. If you had several nested loops, it's usually quite easy to convert them to an expression with summations. Also, you can just work from the outer loop to the inner loop rather than the other way around. It's probably just preference, but I find this method easier to understand and less subject to errors.

Comment: Is one expected to calculate the function by hand? Because I wouldn't be able to do so for this example.

Comment: Do you mean the first expression in my answer? That's just directly deduced from the code you provided.

Comment: How am I supposed to calculate a summation like that (by hand)? I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: I have showed the computation step by step though. Can you follow what I do in every line? Do you know about the arithmetic series? Namely $$\sum_{j=1}^nj=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Comment: Yes I know about that but when there is more than one to deal with (especially when they have different upper/lower limits) it gets really confusing.

Comment: Ah, well you can compute them one at a time. Notice how I first evaluated the right summation in the double one? After that, I could evaluate the entire summation. So $\sum_{j=i}^{N-1}1$ is just adding 1 $N-1-i+1=N-i$ times, so this summation is just equal to $N-i$. So we obtain $$\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i}^{N-1}1=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(N-i).$$ Then splitting the sum yields this to be equal to $$\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}N-\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}i.$$ Here the first sum is just equal to $N$, while the second is an arithmetic series. See how you can split the sums up and compute them separately?

Comment: Thanks. That makes it easier to understand!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help!